# Beginner Swift - Trouble changing UILabel.text to stored property in object

Tags: swift, function, uilabel

Very basic question thanks for your help

Trying to change the text of a UILabel by referring to a stored property in object (jName), so you can change in future / add more names / labels, rather than just explicitly declaring firstName.text = "Joe Bloggs"

Don't understand why it won't let me change text to a stored property of jName? I tried initalising the properties but this didn't help either. Anyone know the best way to structure this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var firstName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var thirdName: UILabel!

    struct jName {

        var fName: String = "Joe"
        var lName: String = "Blogs"

        init(fName: String, lName: String) {
            self.fName = fName
            self.lName = lName
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assignLabels()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func assignLabels() {

        firstName.text = jName.fName
        thirdName.text = jName.lName

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are using struct, there is already a builtin constructor, so this part in your code is unnecessary if you're not puting a custom code on it:

```
init(fName: String, lName: String) {
    self.fName = fName
    self.lName = lName
}
```

It won't let you change the text because you didn't initialize the struct and you're trying to access its properties directly. You should instantiate the struct before using its properties:

```
func assignLabels() {
    let jNameStruct = jName(fName: "Joe", lName: "Blogs")
    firstName.text = jNameStruct.fName
    thirdName.text = jNameStruct.lName

}
```

The other option is to use the `static` modifier in your variables, so you'd be able to access the stored properties directly:

```
struct jName {

    static var fName: String = "Joe"
    static var lName: String = "Blogs"

    init(fName: String, lName: String) {
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am putting some code for hint i hope you will get an idea!

```
struct jName {

var fName: String = "Joe"
var lName: String = "Blogs"

init(fName: String, lName: String) {
    self.fName = fName
    self.lName = lName
}
}

let myname = jName.init(fName: "sanjeet", lName: "kumar")
let mystrng = myname.fName
print(mystrng)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote a struct, you need to create a new instance of it before you can access its properties.

So put this line in your class:

```
var names = jName(fName: "Joe", lName: "Blogs")
```

The above line will create a new instance of `jName`. Now you can use the variable `names` to access the properties:

```
func assignLabels() {

    firstName.text = names.fName
    thirdName.text = names.lName

}
```

From the way you worded your question, I think what you really want is that the label's texts changes automatically when the values of `names.fName` and `names.lName` changes. To do this, you need to add property observers to the properties, and in the property observers, you set the label's text:

```
struct jName {

    var fName: String = "Joe" {
        willSet { firstName.text = newValue }
    }
    var lName: String = "Blogs" {
        willSet { thirdName.text = newValue }
    }

    init(fName: String, lName: String) {
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
    }
}
```